# Limit Microsoft Graph API search to site names only

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API to search for Sharepoint sites. I want to search for sites with a name that starts with Digital_ . I can search with `$search="Digital_"` and that will return me those sites, however it will also return other sites based on searching something other than their name (not sure which property is used). I want to limit the search only to the site's name.

When I try `$search="name:Digital_"` I get no results. How can I search for sites limiting search only to the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `/sites?$search="..."`, you cannot search by a specific property like `name` or `displayName`.

You can try [search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-files#example-3-search-sites) where you can search for site(s)

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query

{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "site"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "Digital_"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It will search for the term `Digital_` in properties `name`, `displayName` and `description`.

To search only by the `name` property, specify the `queryString` like

```
"queryString": "SiteName:Digital_"
```

To search only by the `displayName` property, specify the `queryString` like

```
"queryString": "Title:Digital_"
```

To search only by the `description` property, specify the `queryString` like

```
"queryString": "description:Digital_"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/search/query with post request as below:

```
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "site"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "siteName"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```